# Buying more quota in GCP for Google Apps Script quota

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, quota

I'm facing quota limits of sending mails via Google Apps Script. The limit is 100 a day. I called the support center, but they say the script is out of the scope of Google Apps Service.

They told me I could buy more quota at GCP (Google Cloud Platform), now my question: Do I have to code new scripts on the GCP, or can I somehow connect the Google Apps Script (which is part of Drive and Apps I guess) with GCP?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can link both projects, however, I think Apps script email service would still be limited by it's own quotas.

A possible workaround would be to call the Gmail API directly instead of using the Apps script Gmailapp service.

To call the API you can use the "[UrlFetchApp.fetch()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))" to make the call to the Gmail [send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) endpoint.

To be able to make the call to the Gmail API, you will have to enable it in the developer console, for this in your script go to "Resources -> Advanced Google Services". There you will enable the Gmail API, then you have to click on the link that says "These services must also be enabled in the Google Developers Console."

It will take you to the Developer Console of your Appscript project, there you also have to enable the Gmail API.

The quota for UrlFetch is 20k calls/day, so in this case you would be limited by this quota and the Gmail API quota.